# Different ways of resampling in OLS bootstrap

Tags: regression, bootstrap, resampling

I have a constrained OLS model of form:

$$ y = X\beta + \epsilon
$$

After fitting, it turns out that there is heteroskedasticity present in residuals. Let's say I want to estimate the parameter significance. [Davidson and Flachier](http://qed.econ.queensu.ca/pub/papers/abstracts/download/2001/1000.pdf) suggest a wild bootstrap as follows:

$$
y^{*} = X\hat{\beta} + \epsilon^{*} \\
\epsilon^{*} = f(\epsilon)N(0,1)
$$

where you essentially introduce heteroskedasticity of a given form to the data-generating process, which allows you to simulate $N$ times and approximate the distribution of the parameters.

However, I also encountered another bootstrapping procedure ([Cosma Alisi](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/uADA/16/lectures/08.pdf)), where the bootstrapping is as follows:

$$
\eta = \epsilon / \hat{\sigma}^{2} 
$$

Resample $\eta_{i}$ with replacement, to get $\hat{\eta_{1}}, .., \hat{\eta_{n}}$. Set $\tilde{x_{i}} = x_{i}$. Set $\tilde{y} = \hat{r}(\tilde{x_{i}})$ + $\hat{\sigma}(\tilde{x}_{i})\tilde{\eta_{i}}$. Then analyze the surrogate data $(\tilde{x}_{1},\tilde{y}_{1}, ..., \tilde{x}_{n},\tilde{y}_{n})$ as if it was real data.

How I understand this is that you introduce heteroskedasticity in the former procedure, while you remove it in the latter. Can someone explain the difference?

Comment: It appears that they are both introducing heteroscedasticity into the bootstrap simulations in essentially the same way. The former method is more parametric in that it creates conditionally normally distributed bootstrap samples. The latter is more in the spirit of the classic bootstrap, in that it allows the data to define these conditional distributions.